# What is maximum (ideal) memory bandwidth of an OpenCL device?

Tags: memory, gpu, opencl

My OpenCL device memory-relevant specs are:

```
Max compute units                               20
Global memory channels (AMD)                    8
Global memory banks per channel (AMD)           4
Global memory bank width (AMD)                  256 bytes
Global Memory cache line size                   64 bytes
```

Does it mean that to utilize my device at full memory-wise potential it needs to have **8** work items on different CUs constantly reading memory chunks of **64** bytes? Are memory channels arranged so that they allow different CUs access memory simultaneously? Are memory reads of **64** bytes always considered as single reads or only if address is `% 64 == 0`?
Does memory banks quantity/width has anything to do with memory bandwidth and is there a way to reason about memory performance when writing kernel with respect to memory banks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory bank quantity is useful to hint about strided access pattern performance and bank conflicts.

Cache line width must be the L2 cache line between L2 and CU(L1). 64 bytes per cycle means 64GB/s per compute unit (assuming there is only 1 active cache line per CU at a time and 1GHz clock). There can be multiple like 4 of them per L1 too.). With 20 compute units, total "L2 to L1" bandwidth must be 1.28TB/s but its main advantage against global memory must be lower clock cycles to fetch data.

If you need to utilize global memory, then you need to approach bandwidth limits between L2 and main memory. That is related to memory channel width, number of memory channels and frequency.

Gddr channel width is 64 bits, HBM channel width is 128 bits. A single stack of hbm v1 has 8 channels so its a total of 1024 bits or 128 bytes. 128 bytes per cycle means 128GB/s per GHz. More stacks mean more bandwidth. If 8GB memory is made of two stacks, then its 256 GB/s.

If your data-set fits inside L2 cache, then you expect more bandwidth under repeated access.

But the true performance (instead of on paper) can be measured by a simple benchmark that does pipelined memory copy between two arrays.

Total performance by 8 work items depends on capability of compute unit. If it lets only 32 bytes per clock per work item then you may need more work items. Compute unit must have some optimization phase like packing of similar addresses into one big memory access by each CU. So you can even achieve max performance using only single work group (but using multiple work items, not just 1, the number depends on how big of an object each work item is accessing and its capability). You can benchmark this on an array-summation or reduction kernel. Just 1 compute unit is generally more than enough to utilize global memory bandwidth unless its single L2-L1 bandwidth is lower than the global memory bandwidth. But may not be true for highest-end cards.

What is the parallelism between L2 and L1 for your card? Only 1 active line at a time? Then you probably rewuire 8 workitems distributed on 8 work groups.

According to datasheet from amd about rdna, each shader is capable to do 10-20 requests in flight so if 1 rdna compute unit L1-L2 communication is enough to use all bw of global mem, then even just a few workitems from single work group should be enough.

L1-L2 bandwidth:

[image]

It says 4 lines active between each L1 nad the L2. So it must have 256GB/s per compute unit. 4 workgroups running on different CU should be enough for a 1TB/s main memory. I guess OpenCL has no access to this information and this can change for new cards so best thing would be to benchmark for various settings like from 1 CU to N CU, from 1 work item to N work items. It shouldn't take much time to measure under no contention (i.e. whole gpu server is only dedicated to you).

Shader bandwidth:

[image]

If these are per-shader limits, then a single shader can use all of its own CU L1-L2 bandwidth, especially when reading.

Also says L0-L1 cache line size is 128 bytes so 1 workitem could be using that wide data type.

N-way-set-associative cache (L1, L2 in above pictures) and direct-mapped cache (maybe texture cache?) use the modulo mapping. But LRU (L0 here) may not require the modulo access. Since you need global memory bandwidth, you should look at L2 cache line which is n-way-set-associative hence the modulo. Even if data is already in L0, the OpenCL spec may not let you do non-modulo-x access to data. Also you don't have to think about alignment if the array is of type of the data you need to work with.

If you dont't want to fiddle with microbenchmarking and don't know how many workitems required, then you can use async workgroup copy commands in kernel. The async copy implementation uses just the required amount of shaders (or no shaders at all? depending on hardware). Then you can access the local memory fast, from single workitem.

But, a single workitem may require an unrolled loop to do the pipelining to use all the bandwidth of its CU. Just a single read/write operation will not fill the pipeline and make the latency visible (not hidden behind other latencies).

Note: L2 clock frequency can be different than main memory frequency, not just 1GHz. There could be a L3 cache or something else to adapt a different frequency in there. Perhaps its the gpu frequency like 2GHz. Then all of the L1 L0 bandwidths are also higher, like 512 GB/s per L1-L2 communication. You may need to query CL_​DEVICE_​MAX_​CLOCK_​FREQUENCY for this. In any way, just 1 CU looks like capable of using bandwidth of 90% of high-end cards. An RX6800XT has 512GB/s main memory bandwidth and 2GHz gpu so likely it can use only 1 CU to do it.